# c# Can someone explain this boolean logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean-logic

```
// Example bool is true
bool t = true;

// Convert bool to int
int i = t ? 1 : 0;
Console.WriteLine(i); // 1
```

This converts false to 0 and true to 1, can someone explain to me how the t ? 1 : 0 works?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

```
int i = t ? 1 : 0;
```

Equates to:

```
if(t)
{
    i = 1;
}
else
{
    i = 0;
}
```

This syntax can be found in a variety of languages, even javascript.

Think of it like an English sentence if you swap the colon for "otherwise":

```
bool isItRaining = false;
int layersOfClothing = isItRaining? 2 otherwise 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the [C# Conditional Operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
i = does t == true? if yes, then assign 1, otherwise assign 0.
```

Can also be written as:

```
if (t == true)
   t = 1;
else 
   t = 0;
```

or

```
if (t)
  t = 1;
else
  t = 0;
```

Since t is true, it prints 1.

Answer (score 3):

if t equels true then i=1 else i=0

[ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool t= true;
int i;

if(t) 
{
 i=1;
}
else
{
 i=0;
}
```

For more look [?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) Operator

Answer (score 3):

(? *) this is conditional operator.

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. The conditional operator is of the form

condition ? first_expression : second_expression;

here in you case (true?1:0 ) since the condition is true ,which is certainly setting value of i to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that internally the compiler will inline the statement to the equivalent of:

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(t));

This Convert.x method checks to see if the passed parameter is true return 0 if it isn't.